# How can I trigger CommCare to create user cases

Tags: commcare

I need to have the commcare-user case type exist for all my users in my domain so I can export their location ids. Is there a way to trigger commcare to create the commcare-user cases for existing users?

It looks like if I add user case management to a form the user case gets created when that form is submitted. But for existing users I'd like to not have to rely on them submitting a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick, it looks like once user-as-a-case is enabled for the domain, usercases will be created whenever a user is saved.  I realize this isn't ideal.  You can manually trigger this for an individual user in the UI by making a trivial change (and changing it back, if needed), or similarly in a bulk user upload.
It does look like when user-as-a-case is enabled, there should be a bulk action to add cases for all existing users, although this may not happen immediately.

Comment: "once user-as-a-case is enabled for the domain" ... How do I enable user-as-a-case? Is there a setting or is it just confirguring a form with user case management?